# What's the best way to store session ID in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, ios8

I'm building an iOS app version of a web app and I need to store the session ID that is returned after a user logs in. All other information that I need is not sensitive, so I'm going to store it in NSUserDefaults, but the session ID is the one sensitive piece of information I can't store in NSUserDefaults. What's the best way to store the session ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, in the iOS Keychain of course!

[iOS Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html%20%22KeyChain%20Services)

There are many libraries that help with this task, one of the most commonly used is [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain). Although, you could also read the documentation and figure out how to do it yourself, or reference Apple's examples as a way of doing this.

*links valid as of June 3rd, 2015*

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty secure to store session ID in NSUserDefaults. No other apps can access that.

Although this information can be obtained if you connect the device.

For a more secure way you can always use the built-in keychain access to store the sensitive data

Comment: Never used before. But I think you can try. But try to look for another solution, this cod is 7 months without updates and old pending issues

Comment: You can use `SSKeyChain` to access keychain easier. It's well maintained.

Comment: @MichaelCrowley dont forget to vote the answer as correct if that fits you =]

Answer (score 0):

You can store the session id in NSUserDefaults, it's OK because it is visible to the user as a cookie as well. You can also just store the session cookie as a cookie. If you really want to store it safely you can use the keychain.